# Java Socket connect gives success when connecting to an unknown IP address... why?

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I would like to connect by TCP to a machine given its IP address and its port.
I decided to use the JAVA java.net.Socket class and its connect method as it seems to fit my need.

For testing purpose, as the machines I need to test are not yet available, I tried to connect a local machine on its standard port 80.

But I was very surprised to see that it succeeded with any IP address, even an unknown one: I cannot "ping" it, but the connect method gives me success...

Did I missed something in JAVA Socket understanding?
How is this behaviour possible?

Here is my code :

```
    private void testSocketConnection() {
    try (Socket socketToMachine = new Socket()) {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4"), 80);
        socketToMachine.connect(address, 1000);
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine, throwing connect exception for unknown address.

Comment: damned... is there a possibility that I have a local configuration or something that make any IP "known" and "reachable" ? I really din't understand why I always have "SUCCESS" result with this code...

Comment: try with some malformed ip address format

Comment: using InetAddress.getByName("1x.2.3.4") gives me "UnknownHostException" / 
using InetAddress.getByName("java.sun.com") gives me "SUCCESS" / 
using InetAddress.getByName("java.sunnnn.com") gives me "UnknownHostException"

Comment: Is it correct to use the InetAddress.getByName(hostname) method providing an IP address as an hostname? I didn't found any other way to get an InetAddress class from a String IP address...

Comment: It is fine to use InetAddress.getByName with string IPs. If IPs are use then InetAddress only validates the format of IP.

Comment: To be sure I tried using "InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4})" instead of "InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4")" and indeed it seems to be the same...